# Qt 5.1 QML Split Side by Side

Tags: javascript, qt, qt-creator, qml

Is it possible in QML to split your current scene into two identical scenes side by side?
Much like Qt Creator's Split Side By Side button.

I've tried using JavaScript and Qt.createQmlObject to create a new SplitView control setting the SplitView's parent to the parent of the item I want to duplicate. Then, I set the item's parent to the SplitView (I've try using both JavaScript and the ParentChange), and then using Qt.createQmlObject again to create a duplicate item with the SplitView as it's parent.

This approach has failed so far, and was after a way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a scene which is visually the same, you would probably need to use a ShaderEffect to visually clone the scene instead of Qt.createQmlObject to create a duplicate object tree. The latter would have no relation to the original one anymore.